# Mongoose save fails silently

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this code:

```
balanceModel.findOne({year: parseInt(req.params.year)},function(err,data){

   data.months['weirdber'] = {
       x: 'y'
   };

    data.save(function(e,d){
        console.dir(e);
        res.json(d);
    });

});
```

`null` is printed when I call it, so definitely no error is thrown.

The callback's `d` argument holds the correct data, including the newly added property.

Yet, when I retrieve the collection later, there is no property `1999` in `years`.

I have mad absolutely sure that I do not retrieve the wrong collection later on.

This is my Schema, which I have cut down from a compley one with nested schemas to this, let's call it super simple to avoid bad words, stuff. Still not working.

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var BalanceSchema = new Schema({
    year: Number,
    months: Object
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Balance', BalanceSchema);
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Hell, I meant to write `false`. Anyways, I have updated the question. There is no error.  The above was just meant to be a simple explanation. The real code of course does not just log `!!e`

Comment: Done. I would be super-duper happy if you could recommend a schema for this problem. I'm tearing my hairs out.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165571/updating-a-subfield-in-a-mongodb-document-using-findone-and-save.  But it would be better to make `months` an array to keep data out of your object keys.

Comment: I first declared it as an array. However, I found it would be convenient if I could retrieve a desired month via its name, since this is what is passed to the REST API.

Comment: You can still do that with an array by using the `$` or `$elemMatch` projection operators when querying.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection/12241930#12241930

Comment: i think you need to mark it as changed. though this is 1 yr old questions i will still give my opinion :) try adding

`data.markModified('month'); `before you save :)