# Mongoose can't save() in socket.io call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, mongoose

Here's my setup:

*app.js*

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('game-save-comment', function(data) {
    var result = require('./sockets/games.js')(data);
    if (result) { socket.emit('comment-ok'); }
    else { socket.emit('comment-not-ok'); }
  });
});
```

*./sockets/games.js*

```
var Game = require('mongoose').model('Game');

module.exports = function(data) {
  var gid = data.gid;
  var index = data.move;
  var comment = data.comment;

  return game = Game.findOne({gid: gid}, function(err, game) {
        if (!game || err) {
            return result = false;
        } else {
          game.comments[index] = comment;
          return result = game.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
          });
        }
    });
}
```

I think I may be running into some kind of race condition - but I'm not sure. I've put `console.log` messages in different spots in this code and triggered it. The flow gets into the `save()` function and returns `true` all the way up ... however the document never gets update in the database.

Am I doing something wrong? All I want to do is update the `comments` array at the specified index.

Comment: This solved my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165571/updating-a-subfield-in-a-mongodb-document-using-findone-and-save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not right code, you need to add callback to exported function arguments, and call callback once saving finished. Something like it:

```
var Game = require('mongoose').model('Game');

module.exports = function(data, cb) {
  var gid = data.gid;
  var index = data.move;
  var comment = data.comment;

  Game.findOne({gid: gid}, function(err, game) {
        if (!game || err) {
          cb(err || "Game not found");
        } else {
          game.comments[index] = comment;
          game.save(cb);
        }
    });
}
```

And here:

```
var games = require('./sockets/games.js');
games(data, function (err) {
     if (err) {
        socket.emit('comment-not-ok');
     } else {
        socket.emit('comment-ok');
     }
});
```